# Find the unique words in a text file

Tags: java, string

I'm writing this program in Java to find the unique words in a text file. I want to know if this code is correct as it shows even spaces as words.

```
String[] words;
List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();
words = str1.split("[!-~]* ");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    if (!(uniqueWords.contains (words[i])))
    {
        uniqueWords.add(words[i]);
    }
}
```

For example, if my input is "Hello world! How is the world?" my output array/set/list should have hello, world, how, is, the

Comment: No great harm in reading " " as a separate word, so long as you discard it.  There are ways to avoid that, but not a big issue.  But you need (for efficiency) to use some sort of a hash -- probably a HashSet -- to check your word list, vs doing a linear search (which is what `contains` will do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly modified version of other answers (I like it short and simple):

```
String[] words = str1.split("[!-~]* ");
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();

for (String word : words) {
    uniqueWords.add(word);
}
```

Note: if you want to split on `!` or `-` or `~` or space, you should use this:

```
String[] words = str1.split("[-!~\\s]+");
```

(the dash must be first or last)

Comment: I have a text file of a novel. I want to get the unique words in the novel. Obviously the punctuation marks must be removed.

Comment: IF you only need proper letters, why don't you split on non letters: `str1.split("[\\W]+");`?

Comment: I'll try it and let you know now. Please stay online :)

Comment: Btw, I need words not letters.

Comment: @pratnala Yes that's fine - `str1.split("[\\W]+");` will give you words (it will split the string every time it finds a non-letter character, like punctuation, space etc.)

Comment: And now how to output every word in the set? Sorry, never worked with sets.

Answer (score 5):

You can find unique words by using a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Set is a Collection which contains no duplicate elements.

```
String[] words;
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();
words = str1.split("[\\W]+");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    uniqueWords.add(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to check if the word exists? Set will keep only one anyway

Comment: Better perhaps `for ( String word : str1.split(...) )`?

Comment: @assylias What should the regex be?

Comment: @pratnala Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If we're really going for compact:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.toLowerCase().split("[-.,:;?!~\\s]+")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set does not allow duplicates where as List allows duplicates.

```
String[] words;
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();
words = str1.split("[!-~]* ");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    uniqueWords.add(words[i]); //Here you need not to check with set because it wont allow duplicates
```

Comment: @pratnala here there is no need to check the condition before adding

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use pattern and matchers and drop the result in a Set.

```
public void getWords()
{
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+\\s";
    String match = "hello world how* are. you! world hello";
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(match);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        String group = matcher.group();
        boolean add = words.add(group);
        if(add)
        {
            System.out.println(group);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hello 
world
```

Change your definition of what a 'word' is by changing the pattern.

Comment: But the output should have `hello` `world` `how` `are` `you`

Comment: It depends on your definition of what a 'word' is. Notice that there are special characters on certain words (such as * !). If these are not to be considered words the regex above or "\\w+\\s" should do to match one or more word characters followed by a space. I would not consider "how*" a dictionary word. The code snippet above should solve for any input string.

Comment: But I'm taking input from a novel here. So How* won't occur anyway

Comment: Novel huh ? It gets a bit trickier then. Use the code snippet above but tweak the regular expression to include words with the following characters in them - ' ; , : ( ) $ . . Those can appear in any arbitrary text. Examples - 'Don't; 5$; He likes her (not really); Sentence terminated by a period.'

Answer (score 0):

In case if you would like to get the words that have not been duplicated in the sentence/any sort of text, You can try this:

```
   public static Map<String,Integer> getUniqueWords(String sentence){
   String[] word = sentence.split("[\\W]+");
        Map<String,Integer> uniqueWord = new HashMap<>();
        for (String e:word){
            if(!uniqueWord.containsKey(e)){
                uniqueWord.put(e,1);
            }else{
                uniqueWord.remove(e);
            }
        }
        return uniqueWord;
    }
```